# How to save values from api as a number REACT js

Tags: reactjs

This is the api I am using https://covid19.mathdro.id/api

I need to take the {recovered.value} and divide it by {confirmed.value} and then multiply the result by 100 to get the recovery percentage.
But these values are coming as string and not number//

this is the file

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, CardContent, Typography, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import CountUp from "react-countup";
import cx from "classnames";

import styles from "./Cards.module.css";

const Info = ({ data: { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate } }) => {
  if (!confirmed) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
        <Grid
          item
          xs={12}
          md={3}
          component={Card}
          className={cx(styles.card, styles.infected)}
        >
          <CardContent>
            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
              Infected
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
              <CountUp
                start={0}
                end={confirmed.value}
                duration={2.75}
                separator=","
              />
              <div>
                {recovered.value}/{confirmed.value}
              </div>
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="textSecondary">
              {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
              Number of active cases of COVID-19.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          xs={12}
          md={3}
          component={Card}
          className={cx(styles.card, styles.recovered)}
        >
          <CardContent>
            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
              Recovered
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
              <CountUp
                start={0}
                end={recovered.value}
                duration={2.75}
                separator=","
              />
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="textSecondary">
              {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
              Number of recoveries from COVID-19.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          xs={12}
          md={3}
          component={Card}
          className={cx(styles.card, styles.deaths)}
        >
          <CardContent>
            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
              Deaths
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
              <CountUp
                start={0}
                end={deaths.value}
                duration={2.75}
                separator=","
              />
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="textSecondary">
              {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
              Number of deaths caused by COVID-19.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Info;
```

and I have tried parseInt, in this part of code,for confirmed, but it does not woke

```
const Info = ({ data: { parseInt(confirmed), recovered, deaths, 
  lastUpdate } }) => {
  if (!confirmed) {
    return "Loading...";
  }
....
```

this is my app.js

```
import React from "react";

import { Cards, CountryPicker, Chart } from "./components";
import { fetchData } from "./api/";
import styles from "./App.module.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: {},
    country: "",
  };

  componentWillUpdate() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await fetchData();
    this.setState({ data });
    console.log("data");
  }

  handleCountryChange = async (country) => {
    const data = await fetchData(country);
    this.setState({ data, country: country });
    console.log("data");
  };

  render() {
    const { data, country } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Cards data={data} />
        <CountryPicker handleCountryChange={this.handleCountryChange} />
        <Chart data={data} country={country} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bug on your code. I tried to fixed it and able to run it. Please check the update code here:

```
import React from "react";
import {Card, CardContent, Typography, Grid} from "@material-ui/core";
import CountUp from "react-countup";
import cx from "classnames";
import {makeStyles, useTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    container: {},
    infected: {},
    recovered: {},
    deaths: {}
}));

const Info = ({data: {confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate}}) => {
    const styles = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
                <Grid
                    item
                    xs={12}
                    md={3}
                    component={Card}
                    className={cx(styles.card, styles.infected)}
                >
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                            Infected
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            <CountUp
                                start={0}
                                end={confirmed.value}
                                duration={2.75}
                                separator=","
                            />
                            <div>
                                {recovered.value}/{confirmed.value}
                            </div>
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary">
                            {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
                            Number of active cases of COVID-19.
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                </Grid>
                <Grid
                    item
                    xs={12}
                    md={3}
                    component={Card}
                    className={cx(styles.card, styles.recovered)}
                >
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                            Recovered
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            <CountUp
                                start={0}
                                end={recovered.value}
                                duration={2.75}
                                separator=","
                            />
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary">
                            {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
                            Number of recoveries from COVID-19.
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                </Grid>
                <Grid
                    item
                    xs={12}
                    md={3}
                    component={Card}
                    className={cx(styles.card, styles.deaths)}
                >
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                            Deaths
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            <CountUp
                                start={0}
                                end={deaths.value}
                                duration={2.75}
                                separator=","
                            />
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary">
                            {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
                            Number of deaths caused by COVID-19.
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Info;
```

**You should should use Info Component in your app component like below:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Info from "./Info";

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        let data = {
            confirmed: {value: 245550},
            recovered: {value: 4555},
            deaths: {value: 4534},
            lastUpdate: Date.now()
        };
        return (
            <Info data={data}/>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: it gave me a lot of errors, what did you use to convert string to number?

Comment: Hi, it should work perfectly. As I passed static data li 5434 so it was not need to convert. However, you can use parseInt or Number function to convert string to number.

Comment: I have updated my question, where am i suppose to write parseInt?

Comment: Where you use this Info Component like <Info data={data}/> ?

Comment: but In your app.js, you did not use Info Component

Comment: <Cards data={data} /> is used

Comment: so there are two way, either you must use number data in data object or where ever you used recovered.value, confirmed.value and deaths.value, you need to use conversion there. for example you need to change {recovered.value}/{confirmed.value} to {parseInt(recovered.value)}/{parseInt(confirmed.value)}

Comment: it still shows it as string, even   {Number(recovered.value)}*{Number(confirmed.value)} did not work

Comment: i guess its getting converted to int, but no multiplication happening

Comment: can you please try this {Number(recovered.value) * Number(confirmed.value)}

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked..I am getting values like..4,186/108*100=2.5800286669851, do you have any idea, how to stop it a two decimal places?

Comment: You can use parseInt(parseFloat("2.5800286669851").toFixed(2)). It should return 2.58

Comment: {parseInt(parseFloat( {(Number(recovered.value) / Number(confirmed.value)) * 100}).toFixed(2))} I tried this, its giving error

Comment: Hi, Please try {parseFloat(Number("4186") / Number("108")).toFixed(2))  It will return string  "38.76" and you show this in ui.